# Having troubles with Identity field of SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity, create-table

I'm doing a school project about a school theme where I need to create some tables for Students, Classes, Programmes...

I want to add a Group to determined classes with an auto increment in group_id however I wanted the group_id variable to reset if I change any of those attributes(Classes_id,courses_acronym,year_Semesters) how can I reset it every time any of those change??

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Classes_Groups(
    Classes_id varchar(2),
    Group_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    courses_acronym varchar(4),
    year_Semesters varchar(5),
    FOREIGN KEY (Classes_id, year_Semesters,courses_acronym) REFERENCES Classes(id,year_Semesters, courses_acronym),
    PRIMARY KEY(Classes_id,courses_acronym,year_Semesters,Group_id)
);
```

Comment: Not really sure what it is you want to accomplish - but an identity column will be auto-generated by the database for every record inserted to the table. You can't control the algorithm that generates the next identity value, you can only set the starting number and step.

Comment: Even if all other attributes are primary keys? @ZoharPeled

Comment: Primary key have nothing to do with Identity.

Comment: Identity does not work this way, is a sequence number for each insert you make on the entire table, there is no such thing like a partitioned identity, you need to calculate that value in a different way, one of them could be into an Instead of insert trigger

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you do not (need to) reset the identity column of a table. An identity column is used to *create unique values for every single record in a table*.

So you want to generate entries in your groups table based on new entries in your classes table. You might create a *trigger* on your classes table for that purpose.

Since `Group_id` is already unique by itself (because of its IDENTITY), you do not need other fields in the primary key at all. Instead, you may create a separate UNIQUE constraint for the combination `(Classes_id, courses_acronym, year_Semesters)` if you need it.

And if the `id` field of your classes table is an IDENTITY column too, you could define a primary key in your classes table solely on that `id` field. And then your foreign key constraint in your new groups table can only include that `Classes_id` field.)

So much for now. I guess that your database design needs some more additional tuning and tweaking. ;)

Comment: Yeah i guess ill tweak a little more my previous tables,thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

where are you setting the values from?, you can have a stored proc and in your query have the columns have an initial value set when stored proc is hit assuming there are values at the beginning 
.Then use an IF statement.
                declare @initial_Classes_id varchar(2) = --initial value inserted
                declare @initial_courses_acronym varchar(4) = --initial value inserted
                declare @initial_year_Semesters varchar(5) = --initial value inserted

```
            declare @compare_Classes_id varchar(2) =  (select top 1 Classes_id from Classes_Groups order by --PK column desc for last insert); l would add Dateadded and then order with last insert date
            declare @compare_courses_acronym varchar(2) =  (select top 1 Classes_id from Classes_Groups where Classes_id = @compare_Classes_id); 
            declare @compare_year_Semesters varchar(2) =  (select top 1 Classes_id from Classes_Groups where Classes_id = @compare_Classes_id); 


            IF (@initial_Classes_id != @compare_Classes_id OR @initial_courses_acronym != @compare_courses_acronym OR @initial_year_Semesters != @compare_year_Semesters)
            BEGIN

            DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Group_id', RESEED, 1)
            Insert into Classes_Groups (courses_acronym,year_Semesters)
            values (
            courses_acronym,
            year_Semesters
            )

            END

            ELSE 

            BEGIN
            Insert into Classes_Groups (courses_acronym,year_Semesters)
            values (
            courses_acronym,
            year_Semesters
            )
            END
```

NB: would advice to use int on the primary key. Unless you have a specific purpose of doing so.